# Component renders twice while using custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a custom hook to fetch data from the provided `uri`. But the issue is that the component which is using this custom hook is being rendered twice.

### Codebase

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function useFetch(uri) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!uri) return;

    setLoading(true);
    fetch(uri)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(setError)
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [uri]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}

const App = ({ login }) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useFetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${login}`
  );

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  if (error) return <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>;

  console.log(data?.login);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App login="ziishaned" />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

### Output

[image]